# Interpret java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a system where I through a third party lib gets a date. I know for a fact that the date entered is 1914-08-28 and I don't care for the hours and minutes. I need to deliver this date to the client and it should be formatted like 1914-08-28T00:00.

What I get from the third party lib is a java.util.Date and while debugging I stumpled upon something that to me looked strange.
Take a look at the following image. I have a date that when calling `toString()` it returns *Thu Aug 27 22:00:00 CET 1914*, but when you look at the contained `cdate` it looks like being in Zulu time.

[image]

Formatting this with the DateFormat gives me *1914-08-27T00:00*:

```
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00");
```

What I really expected here is that I have a date in Zulu time (1914-08-27T22:00Z) which is equivalent to 1914-08-28T00:00 CET (the following day).

This can be reproduced with the following code.

```
Calendar instance.set(1914, 7, 28, 22, 0);
instance.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
Date d = instance.getTime();
```

Now `d` will display CET time and the cdate (visible debugging) will show Zulu time, but they are not different. If the default time zone is used I would expect the CET time to be different than the Zulu time.

What is the explanation for this?

Comment: You can use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet that demonstrates this behaviour.

Comment: I am using SimpleDateFormat to format. It formats the date to Aug 27. What I don't understand is that it looks like being in Zule time - and then it's Aug 28 CET

Comment: `Date.toString()` *always* uses the default time zone. There's no value in the `Date` to govern that; it's just a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. Don't use `toString` for anything important - always format explicitly, specifying which time zone you want.

Comment: Ok, what the question really is about here is why I see a difference in the debugger. I know how the toString formats the date, but then why is it not any different that the Zule time. As far as I know CET != Zulu.

Comment: @homaxto: The debugger is showing you implementation details. You shouldn't care about them, basically. I'm not sure what you mean by "but then why is it not any different that the Zule time"...

Answer (score 7):

A `java.util.Date` isn't in any particular time zone - it's just an instant in time, which will have different local times around the world.

Internally, it's a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, but frankly it *could* be a different representation... and although we usually think of "the Unix epoch" as 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, you can equally think of it as 1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00... they represent the same point in time.

Fundamentally, stop thinking about `java.util.Date` as being in any time zone - it's not, and `toString()` always just uses the system default time zone, to the confusion of many developers. Always use a dedicated formatter (e.g. `SimpleDateFormat`) and specify the time zone you're interested in.

Oh, and ideally move to using `java.time` or [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time), both of which are far superior date/time APIs...